# Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature

Tags: typescript, types, compiler-errors, typescript-typings

How do I get the error to stop in my console.log?

> Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.

```
var audioContext = new window.AudioContext();
```

Is the the only way to do it?

```
    var AudioContext = <any>window.AudioContext || <any>window.webkitAudioContext;
    var audioContext = new AudioContext();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default these kind of global APIs aren't defined in the built-in typescript `Window` interface. But you can decalre it on the window through declaration merging like so:

```
declare namespace window {
    const AudioContext:{
        new():AudioContext;
    }
}
```

you should then be able to use it normally like:

```
var audioContext = new window.AudioContext();
```