# Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.ts

Tags: javascript, typescript

I found this, but it did not help me in this instance: [Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543009/cannot-use-new-with-an-expression-whose-type-lacks-a-call-or-construct-signatu)

I have a similar problem. The JavaScript has the following:

```
public clone(data) {
    return new this.constructor({
        ...this.data,
        ...data,
    });
}
```

This is flagged as an error: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.ts(2351)

How can I rewrite in TypeScript?

Comment: think about what you are trying to achieve. Do you want a new constructor or a new instance of the class? How do you normally create instances of classes?

Comment: "I have a similar problem" Similar to what ?

Comment: @Seblor My guess is that this was posted as an answer to another question.

Comment: @Seblor similar to the one described in the link provided!

Comment: @Leon - what am I trying to achieve - conversion of existing Javascript code to Typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd explicitly disable typechecking here:

```
 public clone(data): ThisClass {
   return new (this.constructor as any)({
    ...this.data,
    ...data,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the class is called MyClass,

```
public clone(data) {
    return new MyClass({
        ...this.data,
        ...data,
    });
}
```

should work.